# Asp.NET MVC - Validate a Model Outside of the Controller

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an ASP.NET MVC project and going for the following Architecture:

- A **Core** project that has models, validation, dto, logic, etc.
- A **ServiceStack API** project that acts as my REST API
- An **ASP.NET MVC Web** project that is the UI

So, let's say I want to add a user.  I define a `NewUserInputModel` in the **Core** project.  I give it some data annotations such as `[Required]`.  After doing this, the **Web** project will perform client side validation based on those annotations.

My question is about server side validation.  I want to validate the `NewUserInputModel` using the same rules that are being used on the client side, and I want to run that validation weather the `NewUserInputModel` comes in from the **API** or the **Web** project.

I realize I could call `ModelState.IsValid` from a Controller in the **Web** project - but I want to call that validation from the **Core** project so that all validation logic lives in **Core**.  This way, no matter how this model gets to the **Core** logic, I always call the same validation.  I don't want to leak a `System.Web` reference into my **Core** project.

Is this a reasonable design?  I think it is - but if something about it smells, I'd be happy to hear it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually keep my view models in the Web project and do the *input* validation in the controller using the `ModelState` property. If this succeeds, I map them to domain models (which live in the Core layer) and send those to my services in the Service (could also be Core) layer. The service layer validates business rules and if it succeeds it calls a repository to perform the desired action and returns the result of the operation to the controller.

Keeping your view models in the Web project also allows you to use MVC validation attributes such as [`RemoteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

I'm not saying that your design *smells*, but I do think it's good to separate presentation logic from your Core layer.

Answer (score 32):

I consider your approach to be good. Mapping one set of models to another could bring some bugs.

The code you are looking for is:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

var context = new ValidationContext(model, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results);
if (!isValid)
    throw new Exception("Model is not valid because " + string.Join(", ", results.Select( s => s.ErrorMessage).ToArray()));
```

For details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.aspx or http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this by fast thinking is to do something like that. In business layer create

```
public class ValidationMessage
{
    public ValidationMessage(string message, ValidationMessageType messageType)
    {
        Message = message;
        MessageType = messageType;
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public ValidationMessageType MessageType { get; private set; }
}

public enum ValidationMessageType
{
    Info,
    Warning,
    Error,
}
```

Now having a service example

```
public interface ISomeService
{
    List<ValidationMessage> Edit(SomeModel item);
}
```

Now in the controller you call the service and pass the validation messages to the view. It may be necessary to use ViewBag and pass the whole list. On the view you can highlight Info, Warning, Error. For example you could return some success message with Info type, or nothing at all and in the controller create success message.

Generally this approach is more coding, but more flexibility. Ideally service would validate everything, but for smaller projects to avoid validation duplication, as Henk Mollema stated in his answer, you could do user input validation through ViewModel and in service just validate just critical business rules.

ValidationMessageType may be an overkill as well, so it's possible to return just List from the service as error list and the empty list would mean success.

Answer (score 0):

Making a mixed Validation could be also useful, so mixing DataAnnotations with custom validations logic

This may be helpful
http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2